# Weak form for Linear Dynamic Wave Equation of Dirichlet/Neumann's boundaries?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, linear-programming, wavelets, boundary-value-problem

I have a linear problem with double derivate of space and time, which has Dirichlet boundary condition in $(1)_{2}$ and Neumann's boundary condition in $(1)_{3}$:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta^{2} u}{\delta t^{2}} - c^{2} \Delta u = f \text{ in } \Omega
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
u = 0 \text{ on } \delta \Omega \text{ or}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\nabla u \cdot n = 0 \text{ on } \delta \Omega 
\end{equation}
with conditions

\begin{equation}
u(0,x) = u_{0}(x) \text{ in } \Omega
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta u}{\delta t}(0, x) = v_{0} (x) \text{ in } \Omega.
\end{equation}
**Which is the weak form of the problem?**

**My attempt:**

\begin{equation}
\int (\frac{\delta^{2} u} {\delta t^{2}} - c^{2} \Delta u) \cdot v dx = \int fv \cdot dx,
\end{equation}

for $\forall v \in V_{n}.$
Handling two different parts separately

\begin{equation}
\int_{\Omega} \frac{\delta^{2} u} {\delta t^{2}}v dV
+ c^{2} \Big[ \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v dV 
- \int_{\delta \Omega} \nabla u \cdot \hat{n} \cdot v dA \Big]
=
\int fv \cdot dx.
\end{equation}

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what tags fit your question best. I do know that finite fields don't fit (they have nothing to do with real numbers nor vector fields - they are a concept from abstract algebra). I replaced it with the tag *boundary-value-problem* wishing that it would attract people who can actually help you.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you Jyrky! I completely agree with you. Your tag is good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the result which should be right one.

By integrating and multiplying Equation (1) with $v$
\begin{equation}
\int v \ddot{u} dx + c^{2} v \Delta u = \int fv dx
\end{equation}
using Green I we get
\begin{equation}
\int v \ddot{u} dx 
- \int_{\partial} c^{2} v \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} dS + \int \nabla c^{2} v \cdot \nabla u dx 
= \int fv dx.
\end{equation}

So the weak form is 
\begin{equation}
(v,\ddot{u}) + c^{2}(\nabla v, \nabla u)
- c^{2} (v, \frac{\partial u}{\partial n})_{\partial \Omega} = (f,v). 
\end{equation}